# How to replace 3 words coming from mysql to links

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains one row with a string (for example: 'me', 'you', 'him') and now when I fetch them with PHP I want to replace them with links,

I tried with explode to seperate them and then add links but its not going really well, I started to make a function but it didn't go really well. Can you guys help me to make a function to fetch a string, and then seperate those 3 words and add a certain link for each one of them. the links already exist I just want to replace those words with them.

WARNING: not every row has those 3 words, some have ony the first word some have all of the 3 words.. etc.!

Comment: Can you post the code you used to add the links?

Comment: I think your code will help us to help you

Comment: Replace them in DB or show them as links in website?

Comment: I want to show you my script but I cant because its not allowed here!

Comment: Not allowed by who??? Please, then post some code samples, db examples, etc. Something to help us to understand what you want to do exactly. Don't know for other guys here, but this question confuses me. Probably this is easy task, not a nuclear physics.

Comment: everyone thank you, but I did it by myself finally. it works just like I wanted and just to answer your question " Wh1T3h4Ck5", I am working right now for some company in Germany and everything I do in here is forbidden to me to upload, publish etc.. any codes that we right here.
By the way I want to thank you again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `strtr()` with array argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but I think something along these lines might help:

```
function replace_you_me_him($string) {
    $new_string = str_replace(
        array(
            'me',
            'you',
            'him',

            'Me',
            'You',
            'Him'
        ),
        array(
            '<a href="me.html">me</a>',
            '<a href="you.html">you</a>',
            '<a href="him.html">him</a>',

            '<a href="me.html">Me</a>',
            '<a href="you.html">You</a>',
            '<a href="him.html">Him</a>'
        ),
        $string
    );
    return $new_string;
}

$s = "You, me and him went for a walk.<br/>";
echo replace_you_me_and_him($s);
//<a href="you.html">You</a>, <a href="me.html">me</a> and <a href="him.html">him</a> went for a walk.<br/>
```

Comment: thank you for the function Ben, but its OK now I have already done it. anywayt thanks for your time and help bro.